# Form button style css change to default style in responsive

Tags: css, forms, responsive

The form send button changes from blue styled in my css to html deafult send form button. I want my blue style in any window size. Here is my code:

```css
.form-inline button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.form-inline button:hover {
  background-color: royalblue;
}
```

```html
<form class="form-inline" action="/action_page.php">
        <input type="name" id="name" placeholder="Namn" name="name">
        <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" name="email">
        <input type="tel" id="tel" placeholder="Tel" name="tel">
        <input type="srv" id="ser" placeholder="Välj tjänst" name="ser">
        <input type="date" id="date" placeholder="Datum" name="date">
        <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="remember">Remember me
        </label>
        <button type="submit">SEND</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: your code snippet is working fine

Comment: can you share screenshot?